# Android - Decoding COLOR_QCOM_FormatYUV420SemiPlanar

Tags: android, buffer, codec, pixel, decoding

Im using the Android media codec API to decode some videos. As many of you who have used the API will have discovered, its very inflexible  when it comes to being used on different devices. What i have come across here is when using the US (I747) version of the Samsung Galaxy S3, the decoder gives me back the pixel  buffer in the COLOR_QCOM_FormatYUV420SemiPlanar format.

I have accounted for many different formats before, including YUV420SemiPlanar (color code 21 in android) and they have worked fine, but I cant figure out the pixel buffer in this one. I was expecting a height * width Y plane followed by the U, followed by the V, but to no avail.

Has anyone used this format before? Any help is really appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Jellybean, the `MediaCodec` decoder output formats can be proprietary.  Not only is the format description not published, it's possible that it could change in the future.

In Android 4.3 (API 18), some CTS tests were added that confirm that, if the decoder produces output in one of a handful of "generic" formats, the buffer contents look reasonable.  This is somewhat weak and not helpful for all devices.

If you can work with Surfaces instead, the new features in API 18 may be of use.  Descriptions of and links to some samples and the new CTS tests can be found [here](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/).